# Visual Win-Prolog Listbox Selected Item Index

Tags: visual-prolog, win-prolog

I was going through the manual file `Win-W32.PDF` but I couldn't find how to get the selected item in a listbox.
i.e the index of test3 in this case
[image]

I know that: test being the name, 3 being the id of the listbox
`wlbxsel((test, 3),1, X)` get the status of item 1
`wlbxsel((test, 3),1, 0)` deselects item 1

in the same manner, I tried `wlbxsel((test, 3),X, 1)` thinking it would return the index of the selected item but I got `Error 22 : Instantiation Error`.

Any pointers, documentations, or references are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit confusing at first because of the prefix. we need to use `wlst` not `wlbx`

To get the index of the selected item
`wlstsel((test, 3), Position)`
then get the selected item using the index
`wlstget((test, 3), Position, String, Item)`